# Html.ActionLink yields different results depending on the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, html.actionlink

I've got the URL  `http://localhost:xyz/HelloWorld`, which directs to the `HelloWorld` action in the `Home` controller.

On the page that renders at the URL, I have an Html.ActionLink that points to the same page (yes, a link to the page you are currently on).

The issue is that this link only points to the page if the page is loaded as `http://localhost:xyz/HelloWorld/` (with trailing slash). If the page is loaded as `http://localhost:xyz/HelloWorld` (no slash), it directs to the `Index` action of the `Home` controller.

I've tried several overloads, but I can't figure out what is causing this or how to fix it.

```
Html.ActionLink("Hello World", "HelloWorld", "Home");
Html.ActionLink("Hello World", "HelloWorld", "Home", null, null);
Html.ActionLink("Hello World", "HelloWorld", "Home", new { arg = 0 }, null);
```

These all have exactly the same result. They work fine if there is a trailing slash, and direct to `http://localhost:xyz/` if there is not.

Can anyone explain this behavior or how to fix it?

**EDIT** (possibly relevant?):
When `arg` is present and not 0, the same page is shown at `http://localhost:xyz/HelloWorld/arg`, and has the "Hello World" link (which works perfectly fine), and a similar link that works flawlessly.

```
Html.ActionLink("Argument", "HelloWorld", "Home", new {arg = arg}, null);
```

This points to itself correctly, regardless of whether or not a trailing slash is present.

**ROUTES**:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "HomeStart",
  "",
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
  "Hello World",
  "HelloWorld/{arg}",
  new {controller = "Home", action = "HelloWorld", arg = ""}
);
```

Comment: Can we see how you have your routes setup?

Comment: Your argument needs to be set as optional

Comment: @diaho I've tried it with optional parameters, got the same result.

Comment: @Jim - Just a guess but shouldn't your second parameter to `routes.MapRoute` look something more like: `"{controller}/{action}/{arg}"` (or something that actually applies to your route)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I separated the routes for with and without an argument.

```
routes.MapRoute(
 "Hello World",
 "HelloWorld",
 new {controller = "Home", action = "HelloWorld"}
);

routes.MapRoute(
 "Hello World With Arg",
 "HelloWorld/{arg}",
 new {controller = "Home", action = "HelloWorld", arg = ""}
);
```